# Outlook Web AddIn works in OWA but not in Desktop Outlook regarding input fields

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We are developing an Outlook Web Addin. One of our features is the registration to our system. Therefor we have to collect some data from the user. We are using input fields like:

```
<p>
   <label for="firstName" id="firstNameLabel">FirstName</label>
   <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" required/>
</p>
```

and Javascript code like:

```
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
```

to get the data.
In OWA everythig works fine, but in Outlook Desktop the values of the input fields are not transfered to the Javascript code.

I am using Outlook version 1803 (Build 9126.2275 Klick-und-Los).

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with OWA in IE? When is the javascript code run? Typically the value isn't set until the focus leaves the input control in IE.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, indeed, I have the same behaviour with OWA in IE - I usually use Chrome or Firefox, so I did not mention this. The Javascript code runs after a button click for registration. So all fields should be filled at this point of time.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in IE. Here is an example: https://jsbin.com/marekosijo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for your effort, Meanwhile I suppose it has something to do with the css or the rest of the html. In the second page, where I only have one text field and a checkbox it works fine. Try to reduce the html now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found out what was wrong - it was a very stupid programming error:
For having a one dialog addIn we are importing the different chapters of html from separate scripts to our main html and put it into a displayed current chapter.
Therefor we cloned the chapter after importing, what resulted in duplicate fields in the html. We are surprised why Chrome always took the correct instance and IE and Firefox always took the wrong one. But that's what happened.

But thank you again for your feedback.